# Dimensions of array don't match

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and when I print it i get this output. But I expected to get (105835, 99, 13) as output when printing the print(feat.shape) and was expecting feat to have 3 dimensions.

```
print(feat.ndim)
print(feat.shape)
print(feat.size)
print(feat[1].ndim)    
print(feat[1].shape)    
print(feat[1].size)`    

1    
(105835,)    
105835    
2    
(99, 13)    
1287
```

I don't know how to reduce this. But feat is a MFCC feature. If I print feat this is what I get.

```
array([array([[-1.0160675e+01, -1.3804866e+01,  9.1880971e-01, ...,
     1.5415058e+00,  1.1875046e-02, -5.8664594e+00],
   [-9.9697800e+00, -1.3823588e+01, -7.0778362e-02, ...,
     1.5948311e+00,  4.3481258e-01, -5.1646194e+00],
   [-9.9518738e+00, -1.2771760e+01, -1.2623003e-01, ...,
     3.4290311e+00,  2.7361808e+00, -6.0621500e+00],
   ...,
   [-11.605266 ,  -7.1909204, -33.44656  , ..., -11.974911 ,
     12.825395 ,  10.635098 ],
   [-11.769397 ,  -9.340318 , -34.413307 , ..., -10.077869 ,
      8.821722 ,   7.704534 ],
   [-12.301968 , -10.67318  , -32.46104  , ...,  -6.829077 ,
     15.29837  ,  13.100596 ]], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a smaller example, and include the array so we can reproduce?

Comment: You're showing us the end result of the program, but not how you got there—the example needs more information about how `feat` was constructed.

Comment: It's a 1d array containing pointers to other arrays.  It's likely those arrays differ in shape.

Comment: If shapes are the same, `np.stack(feat)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

the same structure can be create in a more simple way :

```
ain=rand(2,2)
a=ndarray(3,dtype=object)
a[:] = [ain]*3

#array([array([[ 0.14,  0.56],
#              [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]]),
#       array([[ 0.14,  0.56],
#              [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]]),
#       array([[ 0.14,  0.56],
#              [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]])], dtype=object)
```

The problem arise because `a.dtype` is object. You can reconstruct your data by :

```
a= array(list(a))

#array([
#   [[ 0.14,  0.56],
#    [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]],

#   [[ 0.14,  0.56],
#    [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]],

#   [[ 0.14,  0.56],
#    [ 0.9 ,  0.9 ]]])
```

With will have the float type inherited from the base dtype.